# Split one .rar file on Drive into several files before downloading

Tags: google-drive, sharing, download

How I can split one file (.rar), stored on Google Drive, into several files to ease download to my PC?

Answer (score 2):

You can [open a .ZIP or .RAR stored in Google Drive with the Google Drive Viewer](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2011/07/zip-and-rar-support-now-available-in.html) and download each file separately.  It is not currently possible to further subdivide the download chunks beyond the file level using the Google Drive web interface.